# Is there a word for wearing distinctive jewels, clothes, makeup, hairstyle?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for an English word describing wearing of jewelry, distinctive clothing, using makeup or a specific hairstyle (e.g. Roman or Egyptian culture).

I don't know if there is a generic word for that in English.

When I try to translate the word from my native language in English and get things like "adornment" or "set" but I don't know if it fits for a person.

Comment: Sort of : ***sophisticated style?***

Comment: @Josh61 I don't think so... I tried to translate the word from my native language in english and get things like "adornment" or "set" but I don't know if it fits for a person.

Comment: it's totally unclear what you mean.  **give an example**.  do you mean **in a particular style**, say "like an ancient Roman**.  or do you mean **iconoclastic** (use dictionary)

Comment: Well, those are generic terms that don't not really fit the context you are describing.

Comment: Probably *Dress up*: 1) *(Clothing & Fashion) to attire (oneself or another) in one's best clothes*.
2. *(Clothing & Fashion) to put fancy dress, disguise, etc, on (oneself or another), as in children's games: let's dress up as ghosts!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the word ornemental will do it

From The Free Dictionary:

> Adj.  ornamental - serving an esthetic rather than a useful purpose

Answer (score 1):

The word ***fashion*** refers to the specific styles of a chosen culture, or time period:

Keeping with their ***fashion***, the tribe members wear bones in their noses.

"In the 1980's it was *fashionable* to wear safety pins through one's clothing and skin."

Answer (score 0):

If you want to describe the wearing of jewelry specific to an era without stating the era, use **"period jewelry"**.

> "At the costume party the ladies were dressed as women of the past, complete with period jewelry and makeup"